# Docker compose and mysql issues connecting to local db

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, docker-container

Even though I googled as much as I could there's not really anything that worked out for me.

Hence my question:

I am learning docker and docker compose.
I made a dockerfile:

```
# base image
FROM mysql:8.0-debian

# creating user to access db
RUN groupadd -r group-mysql && useradd -r -g user-mysql group-mysql

# required env variable
ENV MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD ale123
ENV MYSQL_USER user-mysql
ENV MYSQL_PASSWORD pass123

# expose the default port
EXPOSE 3306
```

When I docker run the equivalent container and execute a command from the inside of the container the mysql part works perfectly and it allows me to create tables, users dbs and such. There is no connection error.

Now the issue, I created an (in my opinion) equivalent docker compose file

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0-debian
    command: sh -c "groupadd -r group-mysql && 
                   useradd -r -g user-mysql group-mysql &&
                   tail -f /dev/null"
    
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root123
      MYSQL_USER: user-mysql
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass123
    ports:
      - 3306:3306
```

When I run the docker compose up of the aforementioned .yml file and I try to run docker exec -it containername bash and then mysql -u root -p I get this connection error: ERROR 2002 (HY000): Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)

What am I doing wrong? Could someone point me in the right direction?

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

Delete the `command:` line.

If you provide a Compose `command:` override, that runs *instead of* the normal main container command.  In your case the `command:` override runs a couple of commands, then does `tail -f /dev/null`; that "keep the container running" command is running *instead of* the actual database server.

You don't actually need the additional user inside the container.  Nothing in this setup makes use of that user.  The default `mysql` image setup will run the MySQL server as a foreground process, and that's the behavior you need.

Comment: (From what I've seen in other SO questions, you should never need a `tail -f /dev/null` command.  This usually exists to "keep the container alive" so that you can use debugging tools like `docker exec` against it.  But a container is fundamentally a wrapper around a process, and if the container isn't going to do anything, you may as well let it exit and `docker run` a temporary container to debug the image setup.)

Comment: Thank you @David for your input. The reason why I’m creating an user even though it doesn’t do anything it’s because it’ll do something later on. Also why I use the tail is exactly to debug and test mysql.. if don’t have that, how can i test if my docker compose works or my container does

Comment: You should never need to do anything "inside" a database container, though; you'd connect to it with an ordinary MySQL client library or a command-line tool like `mysql`.

Comment: Would you then suggest to connect to it from my own computer mysql cli or spin up another container just for the sake of debugging?

Comment: Yes, both of those are fine.  Myself I'd use the `mysql` CLI locally without any specific Docker setup.

Comment: I am trying to connect from my own computer using the following command mysql -u root -h 172.20.0.2 -p . It asks for my root password then it prints out the following error: ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '172.20.0.2:3306' (60) - it hangs for a bit prior to prompting out the error. The same happens from another container on the same network

Comment: I also tried deleting the " command: " part as a whole but that won't work either. I wonder what's the difference between the dockerfile and the compose.